# How to get all value from input

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following sample HTML:

```
<table id="modem_list">
   <tr class="input_1" name="modem">
      <td>iPad 1<input type="hidden" value="1" class="output_1"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="input_2" name="modem">
      <td>iPad 2<input type="hidden" value="2" class="output_2"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="input_3" name="modem">
      <td>iPad 3<input type="hidden" value="3" class="output_3"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And jQuery script:

```
val = [];
jQuery('input[class^=ouput_]').each(function(i){
   val[i] = jQuery(this).val();
});
```

I am getting an error when using this script, how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

try like so

```
var val = [];
$('input[class^="output_"]').each(function(){
   val.push($(this).val());
});
```

1. you wrote `ouput` instead of `output`
2. wrap the attribute value in quotes `""`
3. (and using push there's no need to use an explicit index for the array)

Answer (score 3):

While the other answers are perfectly valid, here's a slightly shorter alternative using [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), with [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to return an array:

```
var val = jQuery('input[class^=output_]').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Notice that in your code you have written 'ouput' instead of 'output'.

Answer (score 1):

you could have used the same class, you are using wrong class name try:

```
var valArr = [];
jQuery("input[class^='output_']").each(function(){
   valArr.push(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var val= $("#modem_list :input").serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, you have

```
...class^=ouput_
```

instead of

```
...class^=output_
```

you can also write this

```
val = [];
jQuery('input[class^=output_]').each(function(i){
   val.push(jQuery(this).val());
});
```